# full transition after updating query parameters in ember

Tags: ember-cli, ember-router

I have the following route that run a report for specific date range:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.query('report' {
      "report":"my_report",
      "from":params.startDate,
      "to":params.endDate
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    // change format model and save it in rows
    controller.set('model', rows);
  }
});
```

Now, my controller is as follow:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams:["startDate","endDate"],
  actions:{
    processReport:function(from,to){
      this.transitionToRoute('reports',{
        queryParams :{
          "startDate":from,
          "endDate":to,
          "refreshModel": true
        }
      });
    }
  },
  to:"",
  from:""
});
```

The template is as follow:

```
From {{bootstrap-datepicker value=to}}
To {{bootstrap-datepicker value=from}}
<button {{action  "processReport" from to}}>Process Report</button>
```

So, when I click the button the url changed and console show:

```
Attempting transition to reports   ember.debug.js:52602 
Transitioned into 'reports'        ember.debug.js:27426
```

but the page remains same. How do I fully transition to the page?

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your route the queryParams configuration to make a full transition

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    startDate: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    endDate: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
...
```

And on the controller you'll need to just update the values "startDate" and "endDate" in the custom action:

```
Export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams:["startDate","endDate"],
  actions:{
      processReport:function(){
        this.set('startDate', this.get('from'));
        this.set('endDate', this.get('to'));
      }

  },
  to:"",
  from:""
});
```

This has been explained on the guides:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own by reading the updated API on query-params in the following link:
 https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/query-params/

Comment: I have the same issue, but the api doesn't help me... Can you tell me what you did?